# (Simple C++) Getting a matrix with a vector from a file

Tags: c++, matrix, fstream

I'm creating the file with the following code:

```
void Skrivtilfil(double A[nmax][nmax],double b[nmax],double M[nmax][nmax+1],int n, int m){
    int i,j;

    ofstream UdFil;

    UdFil.open("Totalmatrix.txt");

    UdFil<<n<<endl;
    UdFil<<m<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
            UdFil<<M[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        UdFil<<endl;
    }

    UdFil.close();
    cout<<"\nFilen Totalmatrix.txt er Oprettet."<<endl;
}
```

And that succesfully gives me a text document that could 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EhII.png)

So that is working correctly.
Here is my void function that should retrieve the matrix from the txt document:

```
void delA(double A[nmax][nmax],double b[nmax],double M[nmax][nmax+1], int &n, int &m){

    int i,j;
    ifstream IndFil;

    IndFil.open("Totalmatrix.txt");

    IndFil>>n;
    IndFil>>m;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
            IndFil>>M[i][j];
        }
    IndFil>>b[i];
    }

    IndFil.close();
}
```

However, this gives me a wierd result in which my matrix ends up looking
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFX3s.png)

Does anyone have a solution for this? I'm 99% sure the problem is related to how I'm retrieving b[i] from the file.

Comment: That `IndFil>>b[i]` doesn't seem to match anything you write to the file? Did you forget to write it to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You should include `b[]` values also in your writing code:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
        UdFil<<M[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    UdFil<< b[i] << " ";
    UdFil<<endl;
}
```